# matlab tic toc equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, time, timer

I have searched but I can't find an equivalent to the matlab tic/toc function to simply display on the console how long time took the program to do its processing. (ideally I would like to put the tic (start timer) and toc (end timer) anywhere in the program.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This has nothing to do with compilation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found what I was looking for.
Include:

```
#include <ctime>
```

Then at the beginning:

```
 time_t tstart, tend; 
 tstart = time(0);
```

And finally before the end:

```
tend = time(0); 
cout << "It took "<< difftime(tend, tstart) <<" second(s)."<< endl;
```

Comment: The precision for time() is seconds while MATLAB's tic and toc offers milliseconds or better.

Comment: @NoahR `difftime()` returns a `double`, yielding better precision than 1 s as well. The actual precision is system-dependent, as it probably is in MATLAB as well.

Comment: Under C use `#include <time.h>`. But note that at least under Windows, for me it still returns full seconds, even though the return type is double. The milliseconds part is zeroes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485266/how-to-have-matlab-tic-toc-in-c for a higher resolution method. This also works with `time.h`

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the [boost date_time module](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/date_time.html) which might be more portable.

Answer (score 3):

By using `std::chrono` you can write a simple function that performs as Matlab's tic toc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread> // sleep_for, for testing only

void tic(int mode=0) {
    static std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point t_start;
    
    if (mode==0)
        t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    else {
        auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Elapsed time is " << (t_end-t_start).count()*1E-9 << " seconds\n";
    }
}
void toc() { tic(1); }


int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    tic();
    
    // wait 5 seconds just for testing
    std::chrono::seconds sleep_s(5);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(sleep_s);

    toc();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on linux you can use the function

```
    clock_gettime();
```

if on windows try

```
    QueryPerformanceCounter()
```

You can google these for specific implementation details. Other operating systems I dont know about. There are doubtless many other ways to achieve the same thing but if you get no other responses, these are a reasonable place to start.