# How to have matlab tic toc in C++?

Tags: c++

in matlab:

```
tic
do something ...
toc
```

my attempt to have this functionality:

```
#define tic      double tic_t = clock();
#define toc      std::cout << (clock() - tic_t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC \
                           << " seconds" << std::endl;
```

Now I can do this in C++:

```
tic
doSomething();
toc
```

The problem is that I cannot call it multiple times inside a function because tic_t will be defined several times.
I want to do something like this:

```
tic
doSomething1();
toc
tic
doSomething2();
toc
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd implement it as a stack. Then, you can recurse, call it multiple times, do whatever you want, and it won't break, so long as you call `toc()` after every `tic()`. As a bonus, you don't have to resort to using macros:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <ctime>

std::stack<clock_t> tictoc_stack;

void tic() {
    tictoc_stack.push(clock());
}

void toc() {
    std::cout << "Time elapsed: "
              << ((double)(clock() - tictoc_stack.top())) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC
              << std::endl;
    tictoc_stack.pop();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    tic();
    doSomething();
    toc();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either put `double tic_t;` as a global, and `#define tic tic_t = clock();` or add a `#define tictoc_init double tic_t` that you use at the top of each method (and change `tic` as above)

The second way is better since "doSomething()" may contain tics and tocs that would overwrite your global variable.